# Openshift Jenkins build fails to remove temp shell script on builder

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I had a working Django setup on OpenShift with Jenkins building so this has worked before. Now, for couple of weeks I have had problems with Jenkins. Here is one symptom:

```
FATAL: Unable to delete script file /tmp/hudson2562951972265911713.sh
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /tmp/hudson2562951972265911713.sh at hudson.remoting.Channel@1826d31:stablesbldr
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:900)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at hudson.FilePath.delete(FilePath.java:1262)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:101)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:60)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:802)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:584)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: channel is already closed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:494)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:129)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:672)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
.......
```

So Jenkins cannot remove the remote script on the builder machine. I even re-installed the jenkins gear and re-added the Jenkins cartridge to my application.

Comment: I think this has something to do with: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12235

Is it possible to run the build on the Jenkins gear?

Comment: Interestingly, I am looking for the opposite, to be able to keep these files so I can manually execute them for debug purposes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it had something to do with the connection dropping to the slave.
The second comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998520/216846 did the trick for me.

When I contsantly refreshed the node status it showed me that the response time rose as high as 400ms when Django was post processing static files. Maybe that dropped the slave to offline mode.